# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null

Tags: java, android, json, firebase-authentication

I'm new to firebase and was trying to create code for login. Every time I try to press the button leaving the fields empty the app crashes even though I've written the code for the same. I've attached the java code for the same here.

MainActivity2.java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email,password;
    private Button btn;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        email = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        password = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button2);


        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                    //means user has logged in
                    startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, New.class));

                }

            }
        };
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startSignin();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    }

    private void startSignin(){
        String mail = email.getText().toString();
        String pass = password.getText().toString();

        //To make sure user field is not left blank
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mail)||TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Fields are empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mail,pass).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(!task.isSuccessful()){ //user didnt login in successfully
                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Sign in Problem",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I've encountered a problem when I am executing the method it gives me:

```
2020-07-08 17:17:24.276 11020-11020/? E/example.fireap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-07-08 17:17:24.957 11020-11020/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
2020-07-08 17:17:25.381 11020-11020/com.example.fireapp E/GraphicExt: Can't load libboost_ext_fwk
2020-07-08 17:17:25.381 11020-11020/com.example.fireapp E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false
2020-07-08 17:17:25.410 11020-11167/com.example.fireapp E/gralloc: Arm Module v1.0
2020-07-08 17:17:25.411 11020-11167/com.example.fireapp E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2020-07-08 17:17:28.880 11020-11020/com.example.fireapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fireapp, PID: 11020
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of your fields is empty mAuth code will still execute. If you don't want that behavior you have to add else after if branch.

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mail)||TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){
        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Fields are empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
else {
    mAuth ...
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62789333/13146544 Please help @grig